# I need a function or API which convert React Js code into plain Js code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, api, esbuild

I am building a simple HTML, CSS, and JS editor but I want the user to write react in it.
It should be done with any function or API,
I have tried [Esbuild transform Api](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#running-in-the-browser)

```
const onClick = async () => {
  const service = await esbuild.initialize({
      worker: true,
      wasmURL: "/esbuild.wasm/esbuild.wasm",
    }).then(() => {
        esbuild.transform(templateJs, {
          loader: "jsx",
          target: "es2015",
        }).then((result) => {
            console.log(result.code);
            setCode(result.code);
          });
      });
}
```

and it is giving me error

> Uncaught (in promise) CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0

or

> CompileError: WebAssembly.compile()

In short I just want a simple function or API which convert :

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
  }

  updateCount() {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return { count: prevState.count + 1 }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (<button
      onClick={() => this.updateCount()}
    >
      Clicked {this.state.count} times
    </button>);
  }
}

React.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

this react code into simple JS

Comment: Convert "react code into simple JS" -- what does that mean? Do you mean jsx to js? React is not a language.

Comment: thanks, @ChristianFritz for the comment, I don't mean only JSX to JS, I need the complete code which includes the declaration of class to the end of react.render, all the React library code into simple plain js because my HTML, CSS, and JS editor can't understand it